# Access Kivy text value dynamically

Tags: python, kivy

i cannot find an answer to what should be a simple thing. I am trying to make my button display its own **text** value upon pressing it. E.g when i press 'item 1' it should print out 'item 1' and so on. At the moment i get 'item 3' printed out understandably so because it is the last loop, but is there a way to alter the behavior. Please assist:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class test(BoxLayout):
    orientation = 'vertical'
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(test, self).__init__(**kwargs)


        def reload(self, instance):
            print(button.text)

        myList = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']
        t = 0
        for x in myList:
            button = Button(text=myList[t], on_press=lambda instance: reload(button.text, instance))
            self.add_widget(button)
            t += 1

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use lambda as I did below.

```
Button(text=myList[t], on_press=lambda a: print(a.text))
```

whole code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class test(BoxLayout):
    orientation = 'vertical'
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(test, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        myList = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']
        for item in myList:
            button = Button(text=item, on_press=lambda a: print(a.text))
            self.add_widget(button)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Additionally I changed your for loop to be more in line with python conventions using enumerate.

Comment: It works but it's quite a complicated method as i need to use the text value in my 'test' class which i cannot get, sorry i'm new to kivy. Is this the only way?

Comment: No it is not, I think my updated answer offers a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are always getting "Item 3" printed because your reload method is always referencing the last button created. To correct the problem, you need to replace "***button.text***" with "***instance.text***" as shown in the snippet below. Please refer to the example (without using lambda) below for details.

## Snippet

Replace:

```
def reload(self, instance):
    print(button.text)
```

with:

```
def reload(self, instance):
    print(instance.text)
```

## Output - Your Program

[image]

## Example - without lambda

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Test(BoxLayout):
    orientation = 'vertical'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        myList = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']
        for x in myList:
            button = Button(text=x, on_press=self.reload)
            self.add_widget(button)

    def reload(self, instance):
        print(instance.text)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

### Output - Example

[image]

Comment: Thanks both answers work fine, i'll just add the first one as the answer and upvote the other